# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS :Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I add rewriterule to my .htacces file to add 'www' to my website, now they add www but I get always this error to many redirect

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Well, just to give a hint: these rules add `www.` in the front and redirect. Afterwards, they add `www.` at the beginning and redirect. Then these rules prepend `www.` and redirect. And so on...

Comment: I used this I get a 500 error

Comment: And what is written to your server's error log in this case?

Comment: failed to load server

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot WordPress errors, you require to enable WordPress Debug, which can be done using **wp-config.php**.
You need to copy and paste the code in **wp-config.php** file shown below.
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

[How To Debug And Log Errors In WordPress Site](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-debug-and-log-errors-in-wordpress-site/)

Answer (score 0):

In your database check the url's for **siteurl** and **home** in the wp_options table. Are they using www?